# Tshark statistics presicion vs wireshark

Tags: wireshark, rtp, tshark

If I run this command to get the rtp streams statistics through ***tshark***

```
tshark -r rtp.pcap -q -z rtp,streams
```

I get all the calculated values like *jitter* rounded to the second decimal point.

However rtp stream analysis through ***wireshark*** returns these values to the 8th decimal point. I need it through tshark because I need to store the output in a file and parse. So is there anyway to control the precision of ***tshark***?

Comment: Can't you store the output from Wireshark into a file too?